# How to completely delete NetBeans and its components in windows 10

Tags: java, netbeans, ide, netbeans-8

How do I completely delete the associated files of **NetBeans IDE**. I want to uninstall Netbeans and then again install the ide to get default settings and user interface. **But when I reinstall the ide the previous settings are come back.**
Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uninstalling Netbeans and installing Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52124066/uninstalling-netbeans-and-installing-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Have you uninstall it from Control Panel. Uninstal the NetBeans then uninstall JDK and JRE also. You will get the new one if you reinstall after that.

Comment: I have uninstalled the ide from control panel. but not uninstalled the jdk

Comment: Try to uninstall jdk too. And if you uninstall NetBeans any word to say "keep settings file" dont check it. I hope this help.